# Filtering in Laravel

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-8

I have a drop down menu as such:

```
<div class="">
              <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown link
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/filter">Active</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/filter">Inactive</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('Energy')}}">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
```

I wish to select an option from the first 2 items and it should filter the table to show the records based off that selection. In this case I have a a field called "Person" and "Person" can be active or inactive(which is depicted by 0 or 1- tinyInt). When I select Active from the dropdown list, only records that have a 1 in active should show. I am new to Laravel so I was hoping if you guys could tell me if I am on the right path.

my controller:

```
public function filter(){
            $energy = Energy::where('Person', 1)->get();
            return view('admin.add', ['energy' => $energy]);
                        }
```

Comment: You have to select `active, inactive` link individually like `href="/filter/active"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so there's for sure a bunch of ways to implement this, all with different considerations. A simple way to get you going here is to use url parameters:

```
// Your link could look like:
<a href="?active=1">Active</a>
```

Clicking this link in the browser will take the current url and add the params to it: http://example.com?active=1. You can also use the `route` helper to output the full url:

```
// This
<a href="{{ route('energy', ['active' => 1]) }}">Active</a>

// Becomes
<a href="http://example.com?active=1">Active</a>
```

Then in the controller method you can grab the parameters from the `$request` object:

```
// Make sure you import the request class
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


// In our method we check the request for the
// url parameter to use in our query
public function filter(Request $request)
{
    // Here we default to '0' if the request param isn't found
    $energy = Energy::where('person', $request->input('active', 0))->get()

    // Alternatively you could conditionally add the where clause by using the when helper
    // Here if $active is not set the where clause will not be added
    $active = $request->active;
    $energy = Energy::when($active, function ($query, $active) {
        return $query->where('person', $active);
    })->get();
}
```

Check the [Laravel docs for conditional clauses here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses) for more info on that `when` helper

Also worth noting avoid using uppercase characters in your table column names to save yourself some pain e.g. `person` not `Person`

Like I said there's a load of ways to go but hopefully that helps.